# Download file with HTML

Tags: html, file, download

I would like to know what should I write in my .html to make one link downloadable...

I mean, I would like to write something like :

```
<a href="file:///home/user/Desktop/folder/whatever.jpg"> filename</a>
```

and then, when someone clicks on it, do not open another tab, download this .jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add 'download' in anchor tab.

```
<a href="file:///home/user/Desktop/folder/whatever.jpg" download> filename</a>
```

check this link-
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp